# File returns always false for isDirectory and isFile in Java

Tags: java, file

Why file returns false for `isFile()` method, even when it is file. And when it is directory, it returns false for `isDirectory()`. Am I doing something wrong? These files/directories I test don't exists, and I need to create these, so that is why I am testing if I should use `createFile()` or `mkdir()`.

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/John/Desktop/MyDir/file.txt");
if(!file.exists())
{
    System.out.println("Is directory : " + file.isDirectory());         
    System.out.println("Is file : " + file.isFile());
}
```

Comment: "These files/directories I test don't exists" Yes, that is why. Check if it exists, remove the ! from your if statement.

Comment: Name alone is not enough to know if a file-system object is a file or a directory. If the object doesn't exist, you're going to need an external source of information about what it should be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your `if` you're checking if the file doesn't exist. If it doesn't exist then it's neither a file nor a directory.

Java can't determine if your File object is a file or a directory only with a path string. The String could mean a file or a directory (you can have a folder named "file.txt" or a file with the same name).

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is saying if it doesn't exist. If it doesn't exist it is neither a file or directory. Your logic must be wrong as you should use:

```
if(file.exists()){
```

Comment: How can I create it, if I cannot know if it is file or directory ?

Comment: @newbie: It's your program that needs to determine if the user intended to create a file or a directory.  By asking the OS or Java you're asking a *third party* to interpret the input that *your own user* gave you.  It knows less about your users and what they are trying to do than you do.  So you need to glean that information from your user. (If you make it clear to your user, you could assume that any path with a dot in the file name is meant to be a file, and everything else is a directory.  But as a user I would hate that.  Instead separate the gestures for making a file and directory.)

Comment: I'm unzipping package, so I can get that information from zip, thanx for help :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using [`isDirectory()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29) and [`isFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile%28%29) on a file object that doesn't exist. Both of these methods return `false` if the specified file does not exist yet, as per the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

How can it be a file or a directory until it exists?  In Linux and Windows (though Explorer itself doesn't allow you to include a `.`), `file.txt` is a valid name for both a file and a directory, so Java couldn't possibly know how you (or your user) intended to use it.