# Method File.isDirectory() not working in Java

Tags: java, file

```
String baseDirectory = "F:\\Studies";

File folder = new File(baseDirectory);
if (folder.isDirectory()) {
    System.out.println("Folder is  a Directory");
}

File folder2 = new File("F:\\Studies");
if (folder2.isDirectory()) {
    System.out.println("Folder2 is a Directory");
}
```

Here for `folder2.isDirectory()` is returning true but `folder.isDirectory()`is returning false.

My output :
`Folder2 is a Directory.`

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: It is always not working with me too. Try searching the end of string to find a `.` and if so then it is file.

Comment: @Desolator that's about as useless a comment as I have ever seen.

Comment: @Desolator It is always working with me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [File returns always false for isDirectory and isFile in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775659/file-returns-always-false-for-isdirectory-and-isfile-in-java)

Comment: This will always work, you are doing something else. I would use the [NIO API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html).

Comment: @BoristheSpider : No Boris this is not working and I am pretty sure that I haven't gone wrong anywhere. Double checked the code.

Comment: @Desolator : Sorry Its not the duplicate of it.

Comment: @DineshJ If you do the same as u did with folder2, will it work in the first statement?

Comment: @DineshJ Could you reduce your code to a complete, self-contained program that produces the problem? And does F:\Studies actually exist on the computer? Is it actually a file or directory?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have a zero-width space (Unicode character 0x200B) in one of the filenames.  Try re-typing them both, instead of copying and pasting them from somewhere else.

Here's an SSCCE, which I compiled using `javac -encoding utf-8 FileTest.java`:

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String baseDirectory = "C:\\Users\\Lu​ke";
        File folder = new File(baseDirectory);

        if(folder.isDirectory())
        {
            System.out.println("Folder is  a Directory");
        }

        File folder2 = new File("C:\\Users\\Luke");

        if(folder2.isDirectory())
        {
            System.out.println("Folder2 is a Directory");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, the only output I get is `Folder2 is a Directory`.

The reason for this is that I inserted a zero-width space in the value of `baseDirectory`.  As it's a zero-width space you cannot see it.  However, if I open the class in Notepad++ and change the encoding to ANSI (Encoding > Encode in ANSI), the offending line looks like the following:

```
        String baseDirectory = "C:\\Users\\Luâ€‹ke";
```

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation I can think of is that you have a homoglyph problem; i.e. those two string literals *look* the same, but in fact aren't the same.

Reference:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph

Of course ... it is also possible that you have a problem in the way you are compiling your code, and you are not actually runnin code that corresponds to the source code you are looking at.

Comment: F:\\Studies - I don't find any possible way to have a homoglyph problem with this String.. And I didn't type it twice.. I just did a copy paste.

Comment: In that case, the problem must be that the code you are running doesn't match your source code.  Actually, you haven't shown us the real source code.  The code you have shown us is not a complete class.

Comment: Nope...In that case I will not get the output from the second if statement

Is this working for you? Could you please paste the code and your output..

Comment: The code as you posted it, is not compilable. Please see http://sscce.org/

Comment: @DineshJ - 1)  Your argument is flawed.  If you are executing code that doesn't match the source code you are looking at, then **you have no idea what it is doing**.  2)  No.  I'm not running Windoze at the moment.  And besides, as Dunni point out, your code is not compilable.  If you want more help, post an SSCCE ...